# How can I reallocate a triple pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently working on an ai for tictactoe that is implemented in c++ and my progress currently is on its mid way. In my code I have a struct that looks like this.

```cpp
struct Board {
    int config[3][3];
    Board ** nextboards;
};
```

I made nextboards a double pointer because I want to dynamically assign a board to an unknown number of boards. Using an array of pointers will make my storage not dynamic. So to add the possible moves I made a function.

```cpp
void addPossibleMoves(Board *** board, bool xplayer) {
    
    Board * newboard = (Board *)malloc(sizeof(Board));
    Board * another = (Board *)malloc(sizeof(Board));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            newboard -> config[i][j] = compare[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            another -> config[i][j] = compare[i][j];
        }
    }

    Board ***temp = (Board ***)realloc(board, 2*sizeof(Board));
    temp = board; 
    **board = newboard;
    printBoard( **board);
}
```

In this function I am passing in the double pointer by reference to manipulate the data inside. My aim is to re allocate the `**board` with twice the size and insert two nodes to test if it works. But when the code runs the realloc function, it halts and returns a value that is not zero. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Here is my main function.

```cpp
int main() {

   bool xplayer = true;
   Board * startboard = (Board *)malloc(sizeof(Board));

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           startboard -> config[i][j] = compare[i][j];
       }
   }
   startboard -> nextboards = (Board **)malloc(sizeof(Board));

   addPossibleMoves( & startboard -> nextboards, xplayer);
   printBoard( *(startboard -> nextboards));
}
```

*I am currently using devc++ as my ide.*

Comment: First of all, don't use `malloc` or `realloc` in C++ code. Use `new` or `new[]`. Secondly, if you need a "dynamic array" of objects then use `std::vector`. Thirdly, when you want to pass arguments by reference, *use* references. C++ have support for it. Lastly, don't use pointers if you can avoid it. They are easy to get wrong, and you get a lot of things wrong with your pointers.

Comment: I have a background in c that's why i still use malloc and realloc. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: To be frank, then you should know that `realloc(board,2*sizeof(Board))` contains two errors: The first is that you always reallocate the exact same size; The second is that you should be using `*board`. Then think about the following `temp = board` assignment.

Comment: You're also leaking the memory allocated to `another` in `addPossibleMoves`. once allocated and sent through the unnecessary separate initialization (unnecessary because you could just as well initialize it right along side `newboard` in the loop above), it is thereafter abandoned and leaked to the ether.

Comment: I think I need to redo my code. Thanks for the critic.

Comment: @MendrixManlangit I did my own improved version of your code, even 2 versions, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64692586/941531), it solves your current error crashing code. Of cause my/your code can be improved even further, but I just wanted to show you only basics, the rest I can probably tell later if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your code the way I think it should look like. I preserved fully your logic of what code should do. Also I preserved your low level `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` way of dealing with memory. My code still has this triple pointer `***` to show you how to work with it. Also you forgot to `free` memory everywhere later after allocation with `malloc`, you should always free those pointers that were allocated!

Of cause in real C++ code you should use `new`/`delete`/`delete[]` instead of malloc/free. More than that even usage of `new`/`delete` is not that good practice to my mind, better to use those structures that already do all memory management for you, like [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), see my second solution for such example, also instead of keeping plain pointers and manually deleting them it is better to use smart pointers like [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

**First code** below is basically your code but a bit improved.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVNj9owEL3nV1hUrZIAWiC9Zcuh91ZVe6QcQmIWR8GOHLNsW/Hb6diOEzsxVF1pEQIl82bm@c2H87qe51VGn67Xd4Tm1anA6DFvRFGR3TpwXxG2DoJG8FMu0GeW8QL9CRB8CBUoZ3RPnjbJFr6peqsRcYwofhE7@dCkwSUNgmdGCrTnGH8Fg0I1oQcctdE7U37i6JMTTZrPB1JhFMZgNR7yM4iv7fO1FT7tsNMpGPXjRf32qM1iCzkXQNzirWIaykgBTepBWmUbZDWROG7Ib58GMap7h5lWlwqTIbaMQK3zijjOqorlYex4gydwlJnYXmPjSJMw/HNwFO2ZBprrs1lZoqPOYceLWiVHZ3XYtY5LHxmvd6e8tHIsTpxqUK9gzUGb77j@IXiYHzIum7BRx@1UgxDLrjaMo1C@L1Vg@HuUkBTqX0ZdM6ig@3DyvpnMkF0vZfCUXucitMAq3WKUjuh0BNIlMhmx@9Q@wwRNZm0gqzt9tJMBaYf4YlXIQK2i7WCS7abcWlEN@iedRHbrB/8m5VjnYE1AigTNQWkL4MT2DfKo4nfn2VJfmgwlNEUfb02yKVxWFN9Y05Bdhb@wZ3xz0HaMVeilrrJfmA8HgeKzmQVnXpxVhzLKxAHzMeheQ5Dp1Flc/nKXLkpvqbOnxuC1AiohAWnKKEUPDzAWxzrjWNt7sS6tTm9CrpVixC15DTd3qdoLLjL7YbBLncImdhe67nrLGCVTH2IpEe1xvIBVf0VIaY4Zod0itXsKUHB3YrdlGpFxcaO13qQwfcJRbZavqM1ouD7YCewqmMlK/8sPCnQvjLUWev/W1l/Vjsm@UFTVrte/)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

struct Board {
    int config[3][3];
    Board ** nextboards;
};

void freeNextBoards(Board ** nextboards) {
    Board ** cur = nextboards;
    while (*cur) {
        freeNextBoards((*cur)->nextboards);
        ++cur;
    }
    nextboards[0] = 0;
}

void freeBoard(Board * board) {
    freeNextBoards(board->nextboards);
}

void resizeNextBoards(Board *** pnextboards, int cnt) {
    *pnextboards = (Board **)realloc(*pnextboards, cnt * sizeof(Board*));
}

Board * createBoard() {
    Board * board = (Board *)malloc(sizeof(Board));
    board->nextboards = (Board **)malloc(1 * sizeof(Board*));
    board->nextboards[0] = 0;
    return board;
}

void printRepStr(char const * s, int cnt = 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cnt; ++j)
        printf("%s", s);
}

void printBoard(Board * board, int indent = 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printRepStr(" ", indent);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("%02d ", board->config[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printRepStr(" ", indent);
    printRepStr("-", 3 * 3 - 1);
    printf("\n");
    
    Board ** cur = board->nextboards;
    while (*cur) {
        printBoard(*cur, indent + 4);
        ++cur;
    }
}

void addPossibleMoves(Board *** pnextboards, bool xplayer) {
    Board * newboard = createBoard();
    Board * another = createBoard();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            newboard->config[i][j] = 2 * (i + j); // compare[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            another->config[i][j] = 3 * (i + j); // compare[i][j];
        }
    }

    freeNextBoards(*pnextboards);
    resizeNextBoards(pnextboards, 3);
    
    (*pnextboards)[0] = newboard;
    (*pnextboards)[1] = another;
    (*pnextboards)[2] = 0;
}

int main() {
    bool xplayer = true;
    Board * startboard = createBoard();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            startboard->config[i][j] = 1 * (i + j); // compare[i][j];
        }
    }

    addPossibleMoves(&startboard->nextboards, xplayer);
    addPossibleMoves(&startboard->nextboards[0]->nextboards, xplayer);
    printBoard(startboard);
    freeBoard(startboard);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00 01 02 
01 02 03 
02 03 04 
--------
    00 02 04 
    02 04 06 
    04 06 08 
    --------
        00 02 04 
        02 04 06 
        04 06 08 
        --------
        00 03 06 
        03 06 09 
        06 09 12 
        --------
    00 03 06 
    03 06 09 
    06 09 12 
    --------
```

**Second code** below is an improved version of first code, now instead of pointers everywhere I used `std::vector` for automatically managing memory, for plain 2D array of `config` I use [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), for output of text to console I used [std::cout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), also for exceptions catching I used `try`/`catch` and [std::exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

You can see that in vector-based code below you don't need at all to do any work with `malloc`/`realloc`/`free`, because you always can forget to free something after allocating, everything is done automatically inside vector's code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVbb5swFH7nV5xlUgtrS9NkT4XmYdIeJ02b9lRVk2ucxBmxkTFNuqq/PTu2IRiIWGspgZzL952bT2hRXNGciNXh8JELmlcZg5SWOsv54yLoirj0JU@Maql8CVGKPPsC9GF7ygrtC7kstWJk25VtieDFIqhKLlYgyJaVBaEMECEJAnSoqIYvkqgMXgLAY7kcY8qFvoT5wnyASrHkK7iDl9fEGrowU@u7AMH2@tG8lkmABsGT5BkUChF@sOKnViFdE2VASg2foLyEkv9lvzVQoRHzJqrZl1JBWKs2qJgm@EiNVQIXF5vIGplDZaUhTcHQ@Ww2nNAl5NjOwMZ1ZOQiY5Z0eoqUO1KOpNYtdnnHRh1GJgjeuJnjZziByWWNHiVHCwuORn46PvI9f/DAvQw7WTK95HkensN5VP/ehTP72sO63zwYKcaSDGrFRJY76av9Dv6fQUd7hdoO3bQJHVs6hytso/PqErY1JpWWx67QSt3WcO3wRN3Kum6iZRMWXMDnqG05ybLvsiz5Y86@ySdWht2hPIOihTaxyxz2RU6emWqa6CZFsF09JERIvWbKj3o4GY35qeEYbXzPcbT3Q1vT2zuYYbFDjoXYoNf1NdZzWxDFnH487jq5d4fd9RuNemDqgp6/IWivV7FilmFWD1Rfj5OHoE2FkoH6xqiPrcRpMQltCRdh03etnr1r7E8GeuJWZO31cSNSaqJ0Tdct1rDOre1oqUcW3gBhtOjmnPJwtb95Q@1t6/qXyYP0r1Fzg5J3epp1MY7j3fkWIfJCVExXSmCR3BYDSjRdQ@j@C7kUx@XC9v6WbvbR5GtjeIsb0iyofbxbEx1GvfXYAMdxfBLnl/gj5E7AEe/DpL9gX4PD4R8)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Board {
    array<array<int, 3>, 3> config = {};
    vector<Board> nextboards;
};

void printRepStr(char const * s, size_t cnt = 1) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < cnt; ++j)
        cout << s;
}

void printBoard(Board const & board, size_t indent = 0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < board.config.size(); ++i) {
        printRepStr(" ", indent);
        for (int j = 0; j < board.config[i].size(); ++j)
            cout << setfill(' ') << setw(2) << board.config[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    printRepStr(" ", indent);
    printRepStr("-", board.config[0].size() * 3 - 1);
    cout << endl;

    for (auto const & cur: board.nextboards)
        printBoard(cur, indent + 4);
}

void addPossibleMoves(vector<Board> & pnextboards, bool xplayer) {
    Board newboard, another;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < newboard.config.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < newboard.config[i].size(); ++j)
            newboard.config[i][j] = 2 * (i + j); // compare[i][j];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < another.config.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < another.config[i].size(); ++j)
            another.config[i][j] = 3 * (i + j); // compare[i][j];

    pnextboards.resize(2);
    
    pnextboards[0] = newboard;
    pnextboards[1] = another;
}

int main() {
    try {
        bool xplayer = true;
        Board startboard;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < startboard.config.size(); ++i)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < startboard.config[i].size(); ++j)
                startboard.config[i][j] = 1 * (i + j); // compare[i][j];

        addPossibleMoves(startboard.nextboards, xplayer);
        addPossibleMoves(startboard.nextboards[0].nextboards, xplayer);
        printBoard(startboard);

        return 0;
    } catch (exception const & ex) {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "Unknown Exception!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MendrixManlangit I improved my second code to make it more C++-like, besides `std::vector` that was used I also used std::array instead of plain `int config[3][3];`, also `std::cout` for console output, also `std::exception` for catching possible errors.

Comment: for-range might reduce verbosity.